# Take a picture from html5

Tags: javascript, android, html, camera, getusermedia

I read a lot of ways to acquire an image from an html5 page.
I'm still unsure what's the best for my needs:

- wide support for browsers and os: at least: chrome, firefox, android default, safari
- I don't need real-time acquisition. The user must press a button to take a picture, requesting the system camera application

There are at least three solutions :

- `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`
- `Navigator.getUserMedia()` (it seems deprecated)
- `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` (it seems experimental)

Anyway, I see a lot of examples to embed the camera into the page `(w/ getUserMedia)` so I don't know if I can rely only on the first method.

Comment: getUserMedia isn't deprecated, it just changed name to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. If you want to take high-resolution photos on a phone, go with #1, since `getUserMedia` is limited to video resolution atm.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was confused by this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia I didn't understand it just changed the name but it's the same class!

Comment: It returns a promise rather than taking success and failure callbacks, but otherwise is the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the WebRTC getUserMedia API is going to cover all modern browsers apart from Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

[Here](https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/s/webrtc-capturestill/) is an example page that uses getUserMedia to take a still picture (with a link to a [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) describing the code). Most getUserMedia demos show the video stream in a visible canvas area, but that's not required. You can capture an image using getUserMedia without displaying the video stream in a visible canvas.

Unfortunately, Apple has been slow to adopt WebRTC APIs so I think the file input tag is about the best your can hope for there unless you are willing to use something like Cordova. [Here](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/05/20/capturing-camerapicture-data-without-phonegap/) is a description of how to use the file input tag.

The [Media Capture API](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) is a candidate recommendation which means it is on its way to becoming a standard, however, I don't know of any browsers that implement the current W3C recommendation (using a bare capture attribute in the input tag). The `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` style currently only seems to be supported by mobile browsers.

In summary, if you want to have broad browser support in the near future, you are going to need to support both methods until Apple starts supporting WebRTC APIs or until other desktop browsers start supporting the Media Capture API (or the variant with the capture attribute that is currently supported by mobile browsers).

Comment: As far as I understand getUserMedia API allows to embed the camera output into the webpage. Because I don't need to embed anything but just acquire and process (in background) a still image, I think the first method is still better.

Comment: @Mark I updated my answer. If you want broad browser support in the near future, unfortunately, you'll probably need to support both methods. Unless your use is just mobile, in which case the input tag method may suffice (although it may change slightly at some point given the W3C recommendation). I also noted in my update that getUserMedia doesn't need to show the live video. Most demos show it because it's more interesting that way for demo purposes.

Comment: Ok, although my use is only for mobile, it's worth to know getUserMedia doesn't require to show the live video.

Comment: Safari in iOS11 and macOS high sierra is going to come with getUserMedia support.